Concurrent Requests Creating Duplications for Users
I am facing an issue with concurrent requests resulting in duplicate entries. Our system checks whether a user exists and creates a new one if not, using middleware. However, when multiple concurrent requests for a new user occur, each request creates the same user, leading to duplication. Below is the repository code for this functionality.
async somefunction(usrId: number) {
        const t = await sequelize.transaction();
        try {
            const user = await usermodel.findOne({
                where: {
                    userId: usrId,
                },
                transaction: t,
            });

            if (!user) {
                const puraUser = await mainusermodel.findOne({
                    where: {
                        id: usrId,
                    },
                    transaction: t,
                });

                const dob = puraUser.dob;
                const age = dob
                    ? UserRepository.calculateAge(new Date(dob))
                    : 0;
                try {
                    const dbUser = await usermodel.create(
                        {
                            userId: usrId,
                            age,
                            streakDays: 0,
                        },
                        {
                            transaction: t,
                        }
                    );

                    await tblUserSettingsModel.create(
                        {
                            userId: dbUser.id,
                            lowerLimit: defaultUserSettings.lowerLimit,
                            upperLimit: defaultUserSettings.upperLimit,
                            unitId: defaultUserSettings.unitId,
                        },
                        {
                            transaction: t,
                        }
                    );

                    await t.commit();
                    return dbUser;
                } catch (error) {
                    if (error.name === 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError') {
                        const dbUser = await tblUserDetailModel.findOne({
                            where: { userId: usrId },
                            transaction: t,
                        });
                        await t.commit();
                        return dbUser;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                await t.commit();
                return user;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            await t.rollback();
            logger.error(`CREATE_USER for userId ${usrId}`, err);
            return null;
        }
    }

I have tried using isolation levels up to REPEATABLE READ, but the issue persists. When using the SERIALIZABLE isolation level, I encounter deadlock errors.
